# App Crashes when I add ADMOB CODE

Tags: java, android

I am creating my app using telegram's source code, so now am trying to integrate google admob into the application but whenever I do so the app compiles successfully and installs but upon launching it tell me an error as occured and it closes, below is my logcat

```
 01-21 20:29:05.413  21932-21932/? W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
01-21 20:29:05.415  21932-21932/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.telegram.messenger, PID: 21932
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity.onCreate(LaunchActivity.java:131)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below Is my Launch Activity

```
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    public class LaunchActivity extends Activity implements ActionBarLayout.ActionBarLayoutDelegate, NotificationCenter.NotificationCenterDelegate, DialogsActivity.MessagesActivityDelegate {

    private boolean finished;
    private String videoPath;
    private String sendingText;
    private ArrayList<Uri> photoPathsArray;
    private ArrayList<String> documentsPathsArray;
    private ArrayList<Uri> documentsUrisArray;
    private String documentsMimeType;
    private ArrayList<String> documentsOriginalPathsArray;
    private ArrayList<TLRPC.User> contactsToSend;
    private int currentConnectionState;
    private static ArrayList<BaseFragment> mainFragmentsStack = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<BaseFragment> layerFragmentsStack = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<BaseFragment> rightFragmentsStack = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener;

    private ActionBarLayout actionBarLayout;
    private ActionBarLayout layersActionBarLayout;
    private ActionBarLayout rightActionBarLayout;
    private FrameLayout shadowTablet;
    private FrameLayout shadowTabletSide;
    private ImageView backgroundTablet;
    protected DrawerLayoutContainer drawerLayoutContainer;
    private DrawerLayoutAdapter drawerLayoutAdapter;
    private PasscodeView passcodeView;
    private AlertDialog visibleDialog;

    private Intent passcodeSaveIntent;
    private boolean passcodeSaveIntentIsNew;
    private boolean passcodeSaveIntentIsRestore;

    private boolean tabletFullSize;

    private Runnable lockRunnable;

    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ApplicationLoader.postInitApplication();
        NativeCrashManager.handleDumpFiles(this);

        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
        Pushbots.sharedInstance().debug(true);

         if (!UserConfig.isClientActivated()) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE))) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                finish();
                return;
            }
            if (intent != null && !intent.getBooleanExtra("fromIntro", false)) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("logininfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                Map<String, ?> state = preferences.getAll();
                if (state.isEmpty()) {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_TMessages);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.transparent);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (UserConfig.passcodeHash.length() != 0 && UserConfig.appLocked) {
            UserConfig.lastPauseTime = ConnectionsManager.getInstance().getCurrentTime();
        }

        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        actionBarLayout = new ActionBarLayout(this);

        drawerLayoutContainer = new DrawerLayoutContainer(this);
        setContentView(drawerLayoutContainer, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        drawerLayoutContainer.addView(mAdView);
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

App is no more crashing but the ads are not showing also.Here's my logcat

```
01-22 20:02:04.530  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.545  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.545  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.550  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.551  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.566  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.567  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.571  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.571  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.594  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.594  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.607  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.607  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.621  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.621  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.628  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.628  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.645  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.645  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.648  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.649  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.665  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.665  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.670  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.670  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.685  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.685  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.690  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.690  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.706  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.706  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.710  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.710  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.726  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.726  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.731  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.732  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.747  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.749  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.753  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.754  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.769  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.769  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
01-22 20:02:04.789  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw
01-22 20:02:04.789  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger W/AwContents﹕ onDraw mClearViewActive = false
01-22 20:02:04.802  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setContentsSize 400, 50
01-22 20:02:04.803  12233-12233/org.telegram.messenger D/AwContents﹕ setPageScaleFactor 1.0
```

Comment: We need the actual code too. The LogCat data is not enough...

Comment: what is on this line (LaunchActivity.java:131)

Comment: post your LaunchActivity to see what's happen

Comment: ok I will post that now

Comment: I have included the launch activity hope someone will be able to solve my problem

Comment: @TesSal Please see if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get your `AdView` without setting the layout at line

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

Move following code in `onCreate` method of `LaunchActivity`

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

After

```
drawerLayoutContainer = new DrawerLayoutContainer(this);
setContentView(drawerLayoutContainer, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**Update**

As per your comment you are getting error in line# *171*.

*Reason*: You are not loading your layout from xml rather than creating at run time. When you try to get your `AdView` it returns null because its not available in the current layout of the activity.

Do this (Keep previous changes intact, this is additional)

```
AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
drawerLayoutContainer.addView(mAdView);
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: thanks for this fix but now the ad is not showing, but the app is no more crashing